# ADD product directly to paypal cart and redirect user/s to paypal cart in Woocommerce

Tags: paypal, hook-woocommerce

When 'add to cart' is clicked from woocommerce shop page, it should directly add the product to paypal cart and redirect users to Paypal cart.

I am using 'WooCommerce PayPal Payments' plugin instead of 'WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway' because in case of the later,

> This integration method , with 'woocommerce_*paypal_*args' filter hook is deprecated.

So I have to use 'Woocommerce PayPal Payments' plugin. But again

```
add_filter('woocommerce_paypal_args', 'paypal_checkout_order_meta', 10, 2 );
```

filter hook is not supported in 'Woocommerce PayPal Payments'. Can anybody suggest what is the substitute for 'woocommerce_paypal_args' filter?

Comment: What do you consider a "PayPal Cart" ? There is a PayPal Checkout, not a cart, unless you are talking about a very old product that you should not be using. WooCommerce is your cart.

Comment: But, can you tell me whether there is an alternative to the filter, 'woocommerce_paypal_args' which Woocommerce PayPal Payments plugin supports?

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish. Some information about WooCommerce actions and filters is here: https://woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/